# Web API route mapping to root

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am setting up an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API to accept requests from a 3rd party server, and I simply can't figure out how to set the route mappings.
Assume the 3rd party server expects to get responses for:

1. `http://[my_server]/authorize?user=[user name]&session=[session token]&item=[item]`
2. `http://[my_server]/release?user=[user name]&session=[session token]`

Alternatively, the requests can use a dedicated path, i.e.:

1. `http://[my_server]/***api***/authorize?user=[user name]&session=[session token]&item=[item]`
2. `http://[my_server]/***api***/release?user=[user name]&session=[session token]`

I would like to be able to support both alternatives.

Additional requests, following the more traditional `/controller/id` form, should be implemented too, but I'd like to focus on the above (I'm not even sure that Web API is the way to go here).

I have written the following controller:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("authorize")]
    public string Authorize(string user, string session, string item)
    {
        ...
        // return "OK" or "DENY";
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("release")]
    public string Release(string user, string session)
    {
        ...
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

and tried everything I could find in SO and elsewhere in `WebAppConfig.Register`, but I keep getting a 404 error when I try the request in the browser:

```
http://localhost:22332/api/authorize?user=ury&session=token&item=an_item
```

My question is, what do I have to do - specifically in `WebAppConfig.Register` and in the controller - in order to serve the above requests (assuming my test URL is correct...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours working on this and with a lot of help from the [Route Debugger](http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger) - Thanks Phil Haack! - I've found both the problem and the solution.

The problem: Route mapping matching is **ordered**, and `RouteTable.Routes`, from which the app's route mapping is initialized, contains quite a few of them.  The request pattern I was looking for also matched some of these mappings ("authorize" was matched as a controller, for example).

The solution: add "my" route mappings *before* the default mappings.

Yeah, right...

Since most operations are not supported on `HttpRouteCollection`, the resulting code is a bit ugly, but it works:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        routesCopy = new RouteBase[RouteTable.Routes.Count];

        RouteTable.Routes.CopyTo(routesCopy, 0);

        config.Routes.Clear();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "AuthorizeWebApiRoute", routeTemplate: "authorize", defaults: new { controller = "My", action = "authorize" });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "ReleaseWebApiRoute", routeTemplate: "release", defaults: new { controller = "My", action = "release" });

        foreach (var route in routesCopy)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(route);
        }
    }
}
```

As long as "my" route mappings don't match the default mappings (I made them specific enough not to), I'm all good - I think...

Answer (score 2):

You're getting tripped up by Web API conventions for matching a controller name in a URL to a controller class.

If the name of your controller is "MyController", then the URL to request is:

```
http://localhost:22332/api/my/authorize?user=ury&session=token&item=an_item
```

To support a request w/o the "api" bit in the URL, simply add a second route definition in the Register method of WebApiConfig.cs. Since you're also using "actions" in your URL's, you'd need these two routes:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "RootWebApiRoute",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

If you want to omit the "api" prefix as well as the controller parameter, I think you need a different route definition. Something like:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionOnlyRoute",
            routeTemplate: "{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "My" }
        );
    }
```

Here, we'll only look for an "action" in the URL and route everything to your "MyController" class.

Comment: Thanks Mark.
I want to omit not only the "api", but also the controller prefix, and I don't have use for the {id} parameter (unless I'm missing something).
I did try routeTemplate: "{action}", but I'm getting the 404 page.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer. Hopefully this is what you're after.

Comment: Sounds simple, but still no go...  I'm getting 404, resource cannot be found (the resource is "authorize", "release" etc.).
I went over the spelling (the usual suspect) over again and again, and it's ok.  Any idea how to figure out what's going wrong?